# Reading a .dbf file within a Databricks notebook using Python

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks, dbf

I'm quite new to Databricks and Python, and one thing in particular has been really stumping me - I'd be really grateful if someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

I am trying to read a really simple DBF file within a Databricks notebook, using the [dbfread library](https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).

The file I’m trying to read is “people.dbf” (from [here](https://github.com/olemb/dbfread/tree/stable/examples/files)) which is used in many of the examples within the dbfread docs.

I have put this DBF file in the root of my DBFS:
[file_in_dbfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvg8D.png)

But after importing the dbfread module, I get the error below when I try to read a .dbf file:
[dbfread_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3w8t.png)

The file definitely exists, I can see it with dbutils.fs.ls, and if I pretend it's a CSV, I can see the contents with spark.read.csv:
[works_ok_with_dbutils](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MO0d.png)

I've tried using a few other DBF reading modules too (dbf,geopandas,simpledbf) and get the exact same error message. I've also tried copying the file to the local filesystem, and an external location - same error.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with files on Databricks the way how you access them on DBFS depends on the context. More detailed explanation can be found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html). I guess, under the hood, it uses `os` module to open files so, I suggest you try with:

```
DBF("/dbfs/people.dbf")
```

Comment: Hello Partlov, thanks for the reply... I read that article a few days ago and I'm sure I've tried the path you suggested before with no luck... but I've just tried it now and it works! Exactly as you suggested - thanks so much for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at the link - https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html#understand-default-locations-with-examples - it may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you rainingdistros, it is helpful.

I should probably also mention - I only managed to get this working with the cluster in "Single User" mode, and not "Shared". I'm not sure if this was part of the original problem I was seeing.

Comment: Is Unity Catalog enabled?